# How to choose ArrayList element according to a user choice

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList containing Movies.

```
ArrayList<Movie>movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
```

Movie has a property `int movienumber`.

The user can select a movie according to the movienumber, by entering the desired number into the console. 
I store the users choice inside a field `moviechoice`.

How can I store the user-selected movie in the field `Movie moviechosen`, according to the users input?
Meaning, how can I check if the users input matches the number property of a certain `Movie`, and then store this Movie-object in the `moviechoice` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me this sounds like you actually need a `Map<Integer, Movie>` instead of a `List`.

```
Map<Integer, Movie> movies = new HashMap<Integer, Movie>();

// for each movie
movies.put(movie.getNumber(), movie);

...
// retrieving the selected movie
Movie selectedMovie = movies.get(movieNumber);

if (selectedMovie == null)
  System.out.println("Invalid movie number!");
```

(I assume that movie numbers are unique - I believe this is not a strong assumption, since without this, your list lookup would also be ambiguous.)

Apart from using a `Map` being more intuitive and clearer, requiring less code, it also offers practically constant time lookup, while `List` has O(n). If you have a significant number of movies, this is going to make a difference.

Comment: Suppose it's a movie-rental service. In that case he may have a one-to-many relationship from movienumber to movies.

Comment: @aioobe, I doubt that a movie rental, where you more or less regularly get a different movie than the one you wanted, would survive long :-)

Comment: hehe, I'm just saying that if a Movie-object represented a physical disc and the movienumber was a reference the particular movie on the disc, it wouldn't make sense :-)

Comment: @aioobe, my point was, if the movie numbers are not unique, how are you to find the desired movie any better from an `ArrayList` than from a `Map`?

Answer (score 1):

You have no choice, in this case, but looping through the ArrayList and compare the value:

```
for(Movie m : movies){
    if(  m.getTheNumberYouAreTalkingAbout() == numberSelected  ){
        moviechoice = m;
        break;
    }
}
```

If the number is unique, you may want to previously save all the movies in a `HashMap`:

```
Map<Integer, Movie>movies = new HashMap<Integer, Movie>();
```

And use the key of the Hashmap to save the movienumber. That way you just have to do this:

```
moviechoice = movies.get(numberSelected);
```

Comment: Just a side note: _program for interfaces, not implementation_ - hence `Map<Integer, Movie>movies = ...` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

> *How can I store the user-selected movie in the field Movie moviechosen, according to the users input? Meaning, how can I check if the users input matches the number property of a certain Movie, and then store this Movie-object in the moviechoice field?*

Something like this should do.

```
Movie moviechosen = null;

for (Movie m : movies)
    if (m.movienumber == moviechoice)
        moviechosen = m;

if (moviechosen == null)
    System.out.println("Invalid choice!");
```

---

You may also want to consider storing the movies in a `Map<Integer, Movie>`. In that case, you could simply do

```
Movie moviechoen = movies.get(moviechoice);
```

However, note that you could only have a single movie object per movienumber.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
for(Movie movie : movies)
{
    if(movie.getMoveiNumber() == moviechoice)
    {
        moviechosen = movie;
    }
}
```

movieChoice and movieChosen would be better Java names (they follow the standard naming conventions)